# RavenDB with asp.net mvc Update Issue

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ravendb, insert-update

I have a small project in asp.net mvc 3 and I am using RavenDB to store data.
But when i am trying to update entity i have error saying 
"***Attempted to associate a different object with id 'orders/257***'"
I have a service class to menage entities.

This is method to update entity called Order.
I'v omitted the rest of methods baceuse of clarity

```
  public ErrorState UpdateOrder(Order order)
    {
        try
        {
            documentSession.Store(order);
            documentSession.SaveChanges();
            return new ErrorState { Success = true };

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return new ErrorState { Success = false, ExceptionMessage = ex.Message };

        }
    }
```

This is rest of OrderRepository

```
  private readonly IDocumentSession documentSession;

public OrderRepository(IDocumentSession _documentSession)
{
    documentSession = _documentSession;
}
```

ErrorState class is for menagege errors in app, it contains bool success and string message of exception.

This is my edit Actions.

```
 public ActionResult Edit(int id)
        {
            Order order = orderRepository.ObtainOrder(id);
            if (order == null)
            {
                TempData["message"] = string.Format("Order no: {0} not found", id);
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            return View(order);

        }



        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Edit(Order order)
        {
            if(!ModelState.IsValid)
                return View();

            errorState = orderRepository.UpdateOrder(order);
            if (errorState.Success)
            {
                TempData["message"] = string.Format("Order no: {0} has been changed", order.Id);
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            else
            {
                TempData["Message"] = string.Format("Error on update order no: {0} MSG: {1}", order.Id,errorState.ExceptionMessage);
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }


        }
```

This is the rest of the controller , I'v omitted the rest of actions baceuse of clarity.

```
private readonly IOrderRepository orderRepository;
private ErrorState errorState;

public HomeController(IOrderRepository _orderRepository,IDocumentSession _documentSession)
{
    orderRepository = _orderRepository;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You already have an instance of an order with that id.
Check the session lifetime, is it possible that you have the same session across requests?

Comment: Yes I have the same session across requests, that means if I resters the application the database contains all the entries I entered.

Comment: My session is in request scope